Powershell Move-Item fails to move contents of current directory to new subdirectory
I am an absolute novice and have tried to resolve this issue following a variety of tuts and how-tos as well as ChatGPT assistance to no avail. My objective is to reorganize a locally downloaded library of audiobooks by creating a new directory using the author's name, then copying the directory of audiobooks by that author to that new directory as a new subdirectory.
Example
Current directory path =
E:\scripttest\Adrian Tchaikovsky -  Walking to Aldebaran, Narrated by Adrian Tchaikovsky [1630154431]
New Directory path =
E:\scripttest\Adrian Tchaikovsky\Walking to Aldebaran, Narrated by Adrian Tchaikovsky [1630154431]
Thus far, I have been able to isolate the author's name, create the new directory and successfully create a new subdirectory that is also correctly named.

The script checks for the presence of the author's directory and creates a new author's directory if necessary by grabbing text prior to " - "
It then creates a new subdirectory that includes the book title by grabbing everything after " - "
It should move the contents from the original directory to the new book title subdirectory
Once I get the move working, I intend to add confirmation all files were successfully moved, then delete the source directory

Unfortunately, none of the contents from the source directory. Powershell does not return any errors and the script appears to complete successfully. The source directory includes these filetypes - *.ico, *.m4b, and *.jpg. I was hoping to copy the files in bulk, rather than specifying each filetype to be copied in an attempt to keep it simple.
The script so far:
param([switch]$Elevated)
function Test-Admin {
    $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())    $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}
if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($elevated) {
        # tried to elevate, did not work, aborting
    } else {
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -noexit -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
    }
    exit
}
'running with full privileges'
$mainDir = "E:\scripttest"
$directories = Get-ChildItem -Path $mainDir | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
foreach ($dir in $directories) {
    # Extract the author's name and the remaining part of the directory name
    if ($dir.Name -match "^(.*?) - (.*)$") {
        $author = $matches[1]
        $title = $matches[2]
        $authorDir = Join-Path -Path $mainDir -ChildPath $author
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $authorDir)) {
            New-Item -Path $authorDir -ItemType Directory
        }
        $newSubDir = Join-Path -Path $authorDir -ChildPath $title
        New-Item -Path $newSubDir -ItemType Directory
        Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.FullName | ForEach-Object {
            Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $newSubDir -Force
        }
    }
}


Since your paths contain square brackets, use -LiteralPath instead of -Path where applicable


Theo has provided the crucial pointer:

The -Path (-FilePath) parameter of provider cmdlets (which the first positional argument implicitly binds to), expects wildcard expressions.

Because PowerShell's wildcard language also supports expressions such as [a-z] (to match any English letter), paths meant to be literal ones are misinterpreted if they happen to contain [ chars.

To pass a literal (verbatim) path as such, use the -LiteralPath parameter explicitly.

Alternatively, pass a file-information object such as produced by Get-ChildItem via the pipeline to a provider cmdlet, which also binds to
-LiteralPath



For more information, see this answer.



Additionally, it is simpler to use the -Force switch with New-Item -ItemType Directory to ensure on-demand creation of a directory path, which obviates the need for a
Test-Path call.

Specifically, -Force creates any missing components of the specified directory path, if needed, and takes no action if the path already exists in full.
In either case, a [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] instance describing the newly created or preexisting directory is output.




To put it all together in the context of your code, with additional optimizations applied:
# ... 

$mainDir = 'E:\scripttest'
# -Directory limits the output to subdirectories.
Get-ChildItem -Directory -LiteralPath $mainDir |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Extract the author's name and the remaining part of the directory name
    if ($_.Name -match '^(.*?) - (.*)$') {
      $author = $matches[1]
      $title = $matches[2]
      # Ensure that the target dir. exists, using -Force.
      $newSubDir = New-Item -Force -ItemType Directory -Path (
        Join-Path (Join-Path $mainDir $author) $title
      )
      # Move all files in the input dir. to the destination dir.
      # Note the use of the pipeline, which implicitly ensures 
      # binding to the -LiteralPath parameter while also being more
      # efficient than calling Move-Item in a ForEach-Object loop. 
      $_ | Get-ChildItem -File | Move-Item -Destination $newSubDir -Force
    }
  }

Note:

With New-Item, the -Path parameter is used, which effectively functions like -LiteralPath (which this cmdlet doesn't technically support).


Thank you for the explanation and optimization, as well as the additional link! I had to add an additional Move-Item statement to pickup a couple of files in each directory. Added a Remove-Item to cleanup the source directories and everything worked like a charm. Marked as "Accepted".

Glad to hea it, @wrx20l; my pleasure.
